# FFMPEG Media type mismatch for audio only concat

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to run the following ffmpeg filter:

```
[0:a]asplit = 2[acopy0][acopy1],[acopy0] atrim=0:125.400000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0],[acopy1] atrim=197.961000:198.020000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1],[a0] [a1] concat=n=2:a=1[a]
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
[Parsed_asetpts_2 @ 0x557a69d7cf00] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_asetpts_2' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_concat_5' filter input pad 0 (video)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x557a69d7c040] Cannot create the link asetpts:0 -> concat:0
```

Why does it think I need a video and how can I make it only care about audio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `concat=n=2:a=1` to `concat=n=2:v=0:a=1`.

Default is `v=1` so it expects video unless you tell it otherwise.

See the [concat filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) for more info.